# Using Stash image alone not displaying

Tags: stash, image-path

I'm new to the EE using stash i'm getting the output for other fields only image is not displaying. I'm using the stash version 2.6.1. If any one help me to solve the issue it would be grateful!!!

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="product-list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="gshopper_Dresses" limit="5" orderby="date" disable="member_data[pagination|categories" dynamic="no"}
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:p_name}{product_name}{/stash:p_name}
        {stash:description}{product_description}{/stash:description}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="prod_image" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
            {photos}
               {stash:p_images}{product_images}{/stash:p_images}
            {photos}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="product-list" orderby="date" sort="asc" limit="5"}
        <div>
            <h2>{entry_id}:{p_name}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="prod_image" unique="yes" parse_depth="2"}
                <img src="{site_url}themes\default_site\image\{product_images}">
            {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
        </div>
        <div>
            {description}
        </div>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question more fully, and include the code in your question (not as an image).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a misnamed stash variable. When getting the list "prod_image" you have a variable called {product_images} when it should be {p_images}.

Comment: + I think also needs to add "/" to the last {photo} tag

Comment: Thanks all, I did the changes.stash variable is changed to {p_images} and added / to {photos} but still no image is displaying.

Comment: The image is not displayed but if i copy the address of the image and paste it in the browser it display the list of images but in my page i'm not getting image display.(I think it's variable issue but unable to find).

Comment: What is the html that's output for the image tag?

Comment: Just image icon alone displaying in the browser side.I can't see the product images.

Comment: Look at the page source or inspect with your web developer tool... What is the rendered URL there?